# why if $f(x)=0$ , then $x \in E_1?$

Tags: measure-theory

I have  some doubt in Rudin  Real and complex analysis book

Rudin say that if $f(x)=0$ , then $x \in E_1$

My doubt  is given below mark in red box

[image]

**My doubts** : Here $E_1= \{ x: f_1(x) \ge c s(x)\}$

this implies  $x \in E_1$

Here  we are talking about $E_1$

My doubt is that  why rudin didn't mention  $f_1(x)$  ?

why  if $f(x)=0$ , then $x \in E_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0 \leq s \leq f$ so $f(x)=0$ implies $s(x)=0$. Now $x \in E_1$ since we also have  $0 \leq f_1(x) \leq f(x)$.